# Clear out some fields in a sql table

Tags: mysql

I want to clear some columns of this table named 'stats' want to change thier value to zero

```
columns = skills, kills, deaths, hs, tks, shots, hits, dmg, bombdef, bombdefused, bombplants, bombexplosions, h_0, h_1,h_2,h_3,h_4,h_5,h_6,h_7,roundt,wintroundct,winct,assists, connection_time, connects
```

Want to change all the values to zero

[image]

[image]

Can someone plz help me. I don't know much of mysql

Comment: Ph3ro PLEASE remember to accept answers to questions you asked. Of 13 asked in just this stack you've accepted only 2 so far.

Answer (score 0):

It is not **mysql**, it is just **sql**

```
update stats set skills=0, kills=0, ... repeat for each column
```

Read a textbook: [https://www.amazon.com/Understanding-SQL-Martin-Gruber/dp/0895886448](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0895886448)

Comment: I got an error saying "update csstats set skill=0
Error in query (1048): Column 'session_id' cannot be null"

Comment: @ph3ro In the table definition you published in the topic starter the session_id field is defined as "int NULL". Now your error says it "cannot be null". So which is it?

Anyway, read a textbook, without basic knowledge any attempt to help you will result in such confusions.

Comment: Bro, reading that textbook will obviously take lot of time. Currently I need to change these values asap